# Looking for TCP/IP Ethernet <-> RS-485, Half Duplex Device

Tags: ethernet, rs485

We are currently using the [Wiz108SR](http://www.saelig.com/BRD/BRD018.htm) device and need to provide this as a consumer ready component with a power supply. We would rather not build and package the powersupply but instead purchase something that is already done and packaged.

Does anybody know of a similar product that we can buy, rather than this DIY component?

Comment: FYI the title is a little misleading -- it looks like you want ethernet converted to RS485, but the Wiz108SR is apparently an RS485 -> ethernet adapter...

Comment: @Dave, it goes both ways. Saleig just listed it that way. I revised the title, hoping it makes more sense.

Comment: ah cool, ok!

Answer (score 2):

Digi makes an entire [product line](http://www.digi.com/products/serialservers/) of ethernet to serial (RS-485 included) gateways / bridges / servers with various capabilities/levels of hardening.

Answer (score 2):

Easysync do such a device, bit more pricey though!

http://www.easysync-ltd.com/category/126/rs232-422-485-servers.html